# Process that started in an MDI Container stays always on top

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Winforms product. This product has an MDI main window, data presentation forms and a software that is developed for this project which is started in the Main Window if the related button is clicked. The software is called as a process when the button is clicked and it's parent is set to the main window.  Let's say the software is the TeraTerm for the demonstration.

```
 private void barButtonItem2_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Process p2 = new Process();
       ProcessStartInfo ps2 = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\teraterm\ttermpro.exe", "");
        p2 = Process.Start(ps2);
        p2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        var processResult = p2.WaitForInputIdle(10000); // Allow the process to open it's window     
        appWin1 = p2.MainWindowHandle;
        // Put it into this form
        Utilities.HideMinimizeButton(p2.MainWindowHandle);
        Utilities.SetWindowPos(p2.MainWindowHandle, Utilities.HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, Utilities.SETPOS_FLAGS);
        Utilities.SetParent(p2.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);


    }
```

Utilities class is basically a dll import class for the window handling of the processes. Its code is:

```
   public static class Utilities
{

    public static int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    public static int WS_BORDER = 0x00800000; //window with border
    public static int WS_DLGFRAME = 0x00400000; //window with double border but no title
    public static int WS_CAPTION = WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME; //window with a title bar
    public static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
    public static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
    public static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
    public static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
    public const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    public const UInt32 SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200;
    public const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    public const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
    public const UInt32 SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0040;
    public const UInt32 SETPOS_FLAGS = SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW;
    public const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
    public const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;
    public const int SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal extern static int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int value);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal extern static int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    internal static void HideMinimizeAndMaximizeButtons(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
        const long WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000L;
        const long WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000L;

        long value = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);

        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, (int)(value & ~WS_MINIMIZEBOX & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX));
    }

    internal static void HideMinimizeButton(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
        const long WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000L;
        const long WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000L;

        long value = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);

        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, (int)(value & ~WS_MINIMIZEBOX));
    }


    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
}
```

This code is works to put my process as an MDI child. The problem is; the process window is always top of the every child form. I tried calling SetWindowPos with  HWND_BOTTOM but no luck.

You may see from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLXuP.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOgti.png) the process is at the top even it is not activated.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved success using most of the code you used. Here is my image:

[image]

There are a number of minor but obviously important issues in your posted code, making it impossible to know what you're actually doing that is causing the error.

1. You call the `HideMinimizeButton` method but do not provide its definition. In my working code, I called the `HideMinimizeAndMaximizeButtons` method you expose in your Utilities class.
2. You omitted your static extern for `GetWindowsLong` and `SetWindowLong`, so we can't see what you did there...
3. Your `SetWindowLong` call in your utilities class tries to cast the final argument to `int` when the `SetWindowsLong` WinAPI function I see says that it should be `uint`.

My version of your Utilities class looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApp8
{
   class Utilities
   {
      public static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
      public static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
      public static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
      public static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
      public const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
      public const UInt32 SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200;
      public const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
      public const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
      public const UInt32 SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0040;
      public const UInt32 SETPOS_FLAGS = SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE;

      [DllImport("user32")]
      public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, uint dwNewLong);

      internal static void HideMinimizeAndMaximizeButtons(IntPtr hwnd)
      {
         const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
         const long WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000L;
         const long WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000L;


         long value = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);

         SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, (uint)(value & ~WS_MINIMIZEBOX & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX));
      }

      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
   }
}
```

Clearly, this works for me. If it works for you too, kindly accept as the answer.

Comment: I tried bunch of these combinations with SETPOS_FLAGS and it did not helped, I'm afraid. I tried this one too but no change.

Comment: Can you confirm which object `this` is in your statement `Utilities.SetParent(p2.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);`?

Comment: this.Handle referencing to my Main Window's handle. So `this` is my MainWindow class.

Comment: Can you please try to call `SetParent` before you `SetWindowPos` (i.e., swap them around)? Also, confirm that neither handle used in the `SetParent` call is equal to `IntPtr.Zero`

Comment: I called `SetParent` before `SetWindowPos`, no change. Neither process MainWindowHandle or MainWindow's class is equal to `IntPtr.Zero`.

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: Hello @Jazimov, thank you for your concern but I guess I could not make myself clear about the problem. Set Parent works for me it is not the problem. My problem is the process window is always on the top of my other windows. I have a main window, process window and a view window. Process window and view window open in main window. But process window is always at the top, I can not use the view window properly. I added a new screenshot at my question, you may see the problem there more clearly.

Comment: Also I added the full utilities class for your demonstration.